# Python3.4 asyncio(tulip) http framework

Tags: web-frameworks, python-3.4, python-asyncio

I was wondering if there is already some http-server-framework using the new asyncio features. I know about aiohttp, but it's really just a simple server.

In addition: The WSGI standard is not async-driven, is there any work happening for updating the specs ?

Comment: [third party code that integrates with tulip/asyncio](https://code.google.com/p/tulip/wiki/ThirdParty): `tornado` might be possible answer. [About wsgi](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tulip/Gs3bZ2AbS9o)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an implementation based on the [waitress](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/) web server: https://github.com/gawel/aiowsgi

It has pretty much the same performances than waitress (at least with `ab -k` on a small application)
It may become faster than waitress if you use a lot of asyncio ready third party libraries.

The server allow you to use coroutines in your application but since most web frameworks are not asyncio ready you have to use your own code. (it work with a framework but you'll not be able to use coroutines in your application...)

Answer (score 2):

In regards to the WSGI part of your question, the two are in the process of being integrated: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/asyncio.html